# Extract two div tags in one BS find_all

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to extract two HTML div tags in one "soup.find_all" with beautifulSoup? The divs are repeatedly called "event odd", "event even" and i want to loop through them all

**webpage code:**

```
<div class="event odd">
    <div class="featured-image">
        <a href="https://dme-promotions.com/event/gloryhammer-beast-in-black-wind-rose/" style="background-image:url('https://dme-promotions.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Gloryhammer-600x395.jpg');"></a>
    </div>

<div class="event even">..</div> == $0
<div class="event odd">..</div> == $0
<div class="event even">..</div> == $0
<div class="event odd">..</div> == $0
```

My code:

> concerts = soup.find_all(['div', {'class': 'event odd'}, {'class': 'event even'}])

```
for concert in concerts:
    name = concert.find('a').get('href')
```

Comment: Why not simply get all the divs with class 'event' only?

Comment: @Bitto Bennichan Works perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bitto Bennichan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439889/extract-two-div-tags-in-one-bs-find-all#comment103220058_58439889) of using `{'class': 'event'}`.

Or, if you must specify two values at once, you can pass them in a list:

```
>>> len(soup.find_all('div', {'class': ['event odd', 'event even']}))
5
```